# What does this bandpass signal equation indicates?

Tags: wireless-communication, digital-communication

This is the equation for bandpass signal from transmitter. What are the values for different parameters present in this equation. For example, what should be the value of P, Sl(t), Fc etc. Also what is the meaning of j in this equation.

[image]

[Source](http://www1.aucegypt.edu/faculty/kseddik/Homepage/Publications_files/Elmossallamy_ICC_19_AmbNulNC.pdf#page=2) for context.

Comment: Don't think the answer is already present in the image. Example $f_{c}$ is center frequency

Comment: Thanks for reply@ Mahendra , but what is the value for average transmitted power and Sl(t).

Comment: @mahendra I think Sl(t) will also have some equation.

Comment: @charu, I suggest the you use LaTex format to improve readability for symbols such as $\rho$

Comment: @user8055 sure ....from next time I will incorporate this.

Comment: I understood in this equation that S_l(t) is imaginary. But I want to know how this s_l(t) is represented.